# Add project reference to Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, shared-project

I need to add project reference of DTO to Xamarin.Forms project. But Path project doesn't have references.

Problem in this:

[image: Img]

What should I do for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a shared project you will need to add the reference to the Path.droid, path.ios etc... to be able to use it in the shared path section.

Comment: I have tried to add reference to Path.Droid/iOS, but it's doesn't help for Droid project. In iOS project all is OK.

Comment: what kind of project is DTO?